# Auto Transfer Data into Another Sheet OnEdit Google Spreadsheet

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

Needing your kind help to solve my Google script issues.
[image]

I have 3 Tabs on a google spreadsheet, I want to transfer data from 2 tabs into 3rd tab. and this to be performed when I do edit on any of 2 tabs. My code is getting error on **2nd OnEdit function** as below.

"TypeError: Cannot read property 'source' of undefined
onEdit  @ macros.gs:22"

My code is here.

```
function PurposeDrivenMission() {
var spreadsheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
spreadsheet.getRange('\'Purpose Driven Mission\'!D171').copyTo(spreadsheet.getRange('\'All Links\'!GE1364'), SpreadsheetApp.CopyPasteType.PASTE_VALUES, false);

};

function onEdit(e1) {
const range = e1.source.getRange('\'Purpose Driven Mission\'!A1:AA2000');
PurposeDrivenMission();

}



function EightProductivity() {
var spreadsheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
spreadsheet.getRange('\'Eight Productivity Systems\'!D72').copyTo(spreadsheet.getRange('\'All Links\'!GD2'), SpreadsheetApp.CopyPasteType.PASTE_VALUES, false);

};

function onEdit(e2) {
const range = e2.source.getRange('\'Eight Productivity Systems\'!A1:AA2000');
EightProductivity();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

How about this one?

Any edit on the source sheets moves data to the destination

```
function onEdit(e) {
  const sh = e.range.getSheet();
  const shts = ['Source1SheetName','Source2SheetName'];
  const idx = shts.indexOf(sh.getName());
  if( ~idx) {
    const drgs = ['drg1','drg2'];//ranges is A1Notation
    const srgs = ['srg1','srg2'];
    const dsh = e.source.getSheetByName('Destination SheetName');
    const ssh = e.source.getSheetByName(shts[idx]);
    ssh.getRange(srgs[idx]).copyTo(dsh.getRange(drgs[idx]), SpreadsheetApp.CopyPasteType.PASTE_VALUES, false);
  }
}
```

Comment: I think this can't solve my issues.

Comment: I guess I had it backwards